# Game Snake em pygame: Função de crescimento da cobra

Tags: python, jogos, pygame

Estou escrevendo o Snake em pygame, mas, não tenho uma ideia muito clara de como implementar a funcionalidade de crescimento da cobra. Fiz uma lista ("lista_cobra") contendo as coordenadas da cabeça (que tem aproximadamente 30x30 pixeis), e pensei em fazer outra lista a partir desta, contendo as últimas posições da cabeça, excluído o ultimo seguimento, e assim desenhar uma imagem do corpo da cobra ("corpito", também de 30x30 pixeis), a partir dela, a cada ponto acumulado. Essa ideia não funciona muito bem quando ponho em prática, porque do jeito que estou pensado o corpo ainda não consegue fazer o movimento característico da Snake. Minha questão é, como fazer o corpo crescer a partir das coordenadas anteriores da cabeça, mantendo o movimento característico do corpo ?

```
#-*- coding: latin1 -*-

import pygame, sys, os, random, math, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

##### Cores ######
preto = (0, 0, 0)
vermelho = (255, 0, 0)
##################

##################

dimensao = [800, 600]
tela = pygame.display.set_mode(dimensao)

######### Objetos ###########

gramado = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images", "fundocobrinha.jpg"))
paredes = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images", "paredes.png"))
comp = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images", "comidacobra.png"))
comp = pygame.transform.scale(comp, (18, 20))
cabeca = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images", "cabecadacobra.png"))
corpito = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images", "corpodacobra.png"))
corpo = pygame.transform.rotate(cabeca, 0)
caminhodafonte = os.path.join("fonte", "lunchds.ttf")
fonte = pygame.font.Font(caminhodafonte, 22)
fonte_fim = pygame.font.Font(caminhodafonte, 25)

#############################

###### Distancia #########

def distancia(x, y, x2, y2):
    distancia = math.sqrt(((x2 - x) ** 2) + ((y2 - y) ** 2))
    return distancia

##########################

########### cobra #############

pontos = 0
vidas = 3
raio_cobra = 12
raio_corpo = 12
x = [130]
y = [130]

def cobrinha(): 
    global x, y, corpo, direcao, x_modificado, y_modificado

    tela.blit(corpo, (x[0] - raio_cobra, y[0] - raio_cobra))

    if direcao == "direita":
        corpo = pygame.transform.rotate(cabeca, 0)
        x_modificado = 3
        y_modificado = 0
    elif direcao == "esquerda":
        corpo = pygame.transform.rotate(cabeca, 180)
        x_modificado = -3
        y_modificado = 0
    elif direcao == "cima":
        corpo = pygame.transform.rotate(cabeca, 90)
        y_modificado = -3
        x_modificado = 0
    elif direcao == "baixo":
        corpo = pygame.transform.rotate(cabeca, 270)
        y_modificado = 3
        x_modificado = 0

    x[0] += x_modificado
    y[0] += y_modificado

################################

###### Comida da Cobra #########

raio_cCobra = 4
nova_comida = True
x2 = 0
y2 = 0

def comida():
    global x2, y2, comp, nova_comida
    if nova_comida:
        x2 = random.randint(47, 747)
        y2 = random.randint(56, 548)
        nova_comida = False
    tela.blit(comp, (x2 - raio_cCobra, y2 - raio_cCobra))

################################

########## Informações de status #############

def status_de_jogo():
    global pontos, fonte
    p = fonte.render("Pontos: " + str(pontos), True, preto)
    tela.blit(p, (45,37))
    v = fonte.render("Vidas :" + str(vidas), True, preto)
    tela.blit(v, (45,61))

###############################

######## mensagen de tela ######

def mensagem_de_tela():
    mensagem_de_texto = fonte_fim.render("Fim de Jogo, pressione C para jogar ou Q para sair.", True, vermelho)
    tela.blit(mensagem_de_texto,[55,200])

################################

######################################## Loop principal ###################################################

def loop_jogo():
    global x, y, x2, x2, vidas, pontos, distancia, corpo, raio_cCobra, raio_cobra, counter, nova_comida, lista_cobra,lista_corpo, direcao

    direcao = "direita" 

    lista_cobra = []

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    sair_do_jogo = False
    fim_de_jogo = False

    while not sair_do_jogo:

        while fim_de_jogo == True:
            mensagem_de_tela()
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        sair_do_jogo = True
                        fim_de_jogo = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        loop_jogo()

        #### Capturando todos os eventos durante a execução ####
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    direcao = "direita"

                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    direcao = "esquerda"

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    direcao = "cima"

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    direcao = "baixo"

            if event.type == QUIT:
                sair_do_jogo = True

        ####### posição da cabeça da cobra ###########

        cabeca_cobra = []
        cabeca_cobra.append(x[0])
        cabeca_cobra.append(y[0])
        lista_cobra.append(cabeca_cobra)

        tela.blit(gramado, (0, 0))
        tela.blit(paredes, (0, 0))

        comida()
        cobrinha()
        status_de_jogo()

        clock.tick(60)

        fps = clock.get_fps()

        pygame.display.set_caption("Shazam Caraí II ## FPS: %.2f" %fps)

        ########## Se bater nas paredes ##################
        if (x[0] >= 751 or x[0] <= 44) or (y[0] >= 553 or y[0] <= 42):

            vidas -= 1
            x = 400
            y = 300

        ##################################################

        if distancia(int(x[0]), int(y[0]), x2, y2) < (raio_cobra + raio_cCobra):

            nova_comida = True
            pontos += 1

        if vidas == 0:

            fim_de_jogo = True
            mensagem_de_tela()

        pygame.display.flip()
###########################################################################################################

loop_jogo()
```

Comment: Olá. A sua pergunta não está clara. Você explica que "não tem muita ideia", mas apresenta um código que fez. Qual é exatamente a dificuldade nesse código? Por que *essa ideia* não funciona? Forneça mais detalhes pra evitar receber negativações ou votos pra fechar como não clara. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e, principalmente, leia [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem na verdade estudar todo o seu código - A idéia do Snake é que o tempo todo você não precisa se preocupar com os segmentos "do meio" da cobra - (exceto para verificar colisão) - 
A cada atualização do estado do jogo você só precisa se preocupar com a última parte da cobra, e a cabeça.

Outra coisa - uma lsita é uma estrutura legal para guardar dados sobre a cobra,  e tudo que vocẽ precisa fazer é:

1) em cada atualização do jogo
   - acrescente uma nova posição para a cabeça na direção do movimento
   - se a cobra não está crescendo (movimento normal):
         - remova o último segmento da cobra

Outra coisa - notei que no seu código você mantem uma lista de números separados para coordenadas x e y - isso vai te enrolar: quarde semrpe as coordenadas em conjunto como uma tupla de 2 elementos (é como o Pygame consome coordenadas também). Se sentir  necessidade, você pode até usar um objeto de coordenadas mais sofisticado, com atributo x e y - mas você vai querer fazer isso quando aprender melhor a linguagem.

Então, de novo, sem uma análise linha a linha do seu código - você só precisa de uma única lista "cobra" -(não uma separada para cabeça, etc...)

```
cima = (0, -1)
baixo = (0, 1)
direita = (1, 0)
esquerda = (0, 1)

# POsicao inicial da cobra
cobra = [(10, 10)] 

aumentando_de_tamanho = 0
while not sair_do_jogo:
    ...
    # código para saber a direcao do moviemnto a partir do teclado
    ...
    # nova posicao da cabeça:
    x = cobra[0][0] + direcao[0]
    y = cobra[0][1]  + direcao[1]
    cobra = cobra.insert(0, (x, y))
    if not aumentando_de_tamanho:
        # remove ultimo segmento da cobra:
        cobra.pop()
    else:
         aumentando_de_tamanho += 1
    #verificar colisoes de morte:
    ...
    # verificar colisao com comida - 
    if cobra[0] == comida: # (vai  funcionar automaticamente se voce
                           # usar o esquema de coordenadas para a posição da comida taambém
         aumentando_de_tamanho += 5

    ...
```